# mongod ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14

Tags: linux, mongodb

I got the following error when I tried to restart the db after the server (a linux VM) rebooted without shutting down the db first.  I saw someone posted the same error over one and half years ago, but the solution proposed there didn't apply to my situation because it's not a yaml config issue (the db had been running for quite a while). I also included the log at the end. Thanks for any help.

```
  sudo mongod --fork --logpath /nas/is1/bin/mongodb/data/db/mongodb.log --dbpath /nas/is1/bin/mongodb/data/db
  about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
  forked process: 20085
  ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14
```

output in the log file.

```
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=20085 port=27017 dbpath=/data/mongodb/data/db 64-bit host=raboso
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.1
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { processManagement: { fork: true }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/mongodb/data/db" }, systemLog: { destination: "file", path: "/data/mongodb/data/db/mongodb.log" } }
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.329-0500 I -        [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/mongodb/data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
    2017-01-19T15:33:45.346-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=112G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
    2017-01-19T15:33:54.009-0500 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger (-31802) [1484858034:9041][20085:0x7f0fcf72bcc0], file:sizeStorer.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: sizeStorer.wt read error: failed to read 4096 bytes at offset 49152: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error
    2017-01-19T15:33:54.011-0500 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status UnknownError -31802: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_size_storer.cpp 67
    2017-01-19T15:33:54.022-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
     0x12cf722 0x127ac14 0x1266dad 0x1058db2 0x10425ea 0x103f540 0xf679a8 0x93bc91 0x9403b9 0x7f0fce33bb35 0x939829
    ----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
    {"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"ECF722"},{"b":"400000","o":"E7AC14"},{"b":"400000",
    "o":"E66DAD"},{"b":"400000","o":"C58DB2"},{"b":"400000","o":"C425EA"},{"b":"400000",
    "o":"C3F540"},{"b":"400000","o":"B679A8"},{"b":"400000","o":"53BC91"},{"b":"400000",
    "o":"5403B9"},{"b":"7F0FCE31A000","o":"21B35"},{"b":"400000","o":"539829"}],
    "processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.2.1", "gitVersion" : "a14d55980c2cdc565d4704a7e3ad37e4e535c1b2",
    "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64",
    "version" : "#1 SMP Wed Nov 16 13:15:13 EST 2016", "machine" : "x86_64" },
    "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000" }, { "b" : "7FFEF9CD5000", "elfType" : 3 },
    { "b" : "7F0FCF31B000", "path" : "/lib64/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3 }, { "b" : "7F0FCF117000",
    "path" : "/lib64/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3 }, { "b" : "7F0FCEE0F000", "path" : "/lib64/libstdc++.so.6",
    "elfType" : 3 }, { "b" : "7F0FCEB0D000", "path" : "/lib64/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3 },
    { "b" : "7F0FCE8F7000", "path" : "/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3 }, { "b" : "7F0FCE6DB000",
    "path" : "/lib64/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3 }, { "b" : "7F0FCE31A000", "path" : "/lib64/libc.so.6",
    "elfType" : 3 }, { "b" : "7F0FCF523000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3 } ] }}
     mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x12cf722]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo10logContextEPKc+0x134) [0x127ac14]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo17invariantOKFailedEPKcRKNS_6StatusES1_j+0xAD) [0x1266dad]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo20WiredTigerSizeStorerC1EP15__wt_connectionRKSs+0x222) [0x1058db2]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo18WiredTigerKVEngineC2ERKSsS2_S2_mbbb+0x6DA) [0x10425ea]
     mongod(+0xC3F540) [0x103f540]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo20ServiceContextMongoD29initializeGlobalStorageEngineEv+0x588) [0xf679a8]
     mongod(_ZN5mongo13initAndListenEi+0x321) [0x93bc91]
     mongod(main+0x149) [0x9403b9]
     libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xF5) [0x7f0fce33bb35]
     mongod(+0x539829) [0x939829]
    -----  END BACKTRACE  -----
    2017-01-19T15:33:54.022-0500 I -        [initandlisten]

    ***aborting after invariant() failure
```

Answer (score 1):

If a system running MongoDB with the WiredTiger storage engine crashes or experiences an unclean shutdown, MongoDB may not be able to recover data files on restart if the crash/shutdown interrupted a WiredTiger checkpoint.

MongoDB cannot automatically recover data files on restart.

Sadly there is no workaround. Either you can restore data from backups or [resync from another replica set member](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to restore the db from backup.

Answer (score 0):

> WiredTiger (-31802) [1484858034:9041][20085:0x7f0fcf72bcc0], file:sizeStorer.wt, WT_SESSION.open_cursor: sizeStorer.wt read error: failed to read 4096 bytes at offset 49152: WT_ERROR: non-specific WiredTiger error

Above error suggets that your database has been corrupted. Repair it by:

```
mongod --repair --dbpath /path/to/data/db
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that if it happens again (hope not ;-))